# Pivot foreign keys to rows

Tags: sql

I have two tables I need to join together, but instead of them being just more of the same record, I want them to come back with a "labeled" column as rows.

I have a setup like so:

```
create table main_record(
  id int not null primary key,
  foo_entry_id int not null,
  bar_entry_id int not null
);

create table entry (
  id int not null primary key,
  entry_value varchar(255) not null
);

insert into entry values (1, 'foo');
insert into entry values (2, 'bar');

insert into main_record values (1, 1, 2);

select
    case when e1.id is null then 'should be foo'
    else 'should be bar' end as a_label,
    e1.id as foo_id,
    e2.id as bar_id
from main_record mr
left join entry e1 on mr.foo_entry_id = e1.id
left join entry e2 on mr.bar_entry_id = e2.id;
```

I only get one record back:

```
+ ------------- + ----------- + ----------- +
| a_label       | foo_id      | bar_id      |
+ ------------- + ----------- + ----------- +
| should be bar | 1           | 2           |
+ ------------- + ----------- + ----------- +
```

Where I need something like this:

```
+ ------------- + ----------- + ----------- +
| a_label       | foo_id      | bar_id      |
+ ------------- + ----------- + ----------- +
| should be foo | 1           | NULL        |
+ ------------- + ----------- + ----------- +
| should be bar | NULL        | 2           |
+ ------------- + ----------- + ----------- +
```

### EDIT

I'm currently using a `UNION` to do this, but for the sake of the post length, I left the rest out. I'm trying to avoid the `UNION` so I can do this for just a portion of my larger query.

Answer (score 0):

Do the two `JOIN` separately and append the results together with `UNION`

```
select
   'should be foo'  a_label,
     e.id  foo_id,
     null  bar_id
from main_record mr
left join entry e
on mr.foo_entry_id = e.id
union
select
   'should be bar',
     null, 
     e.id   
from main_record mr
left join entry e
on mr.bar_entry_id = e.id
```

Comment: I would do `UNION ALL` just to be on the safe side

Comment: I have to do this 4 times with much bigger queries, i'm hoping to avoid `UNION` (I actually am using a `UNION` now). I should have mentioned this in the OP, I'm updating it now.